# Sound effects library that is full of big rocks!

Tags: library, rocks, prosumer

Hey all,

I'm wondering if anyone has made use of a library that contains lots of nice large rock slides, scrapes and impacts? We have the 6000 and DigiSeries at work and although they are pretty comprehensive I'm so bored of them.

We're doing a cartoon that's going to need a lot of them. I had suggested we bought the Sound Ideas Skywalker library but it'd be good to demo them all first (plus they are low audio spec).

My question might be answered if anyone had had the idea and was about to release a prosumer/boutique library that fitted my requirements (I'm too busy to make my own extensive one at the moment or I would)?

Ian

Answer (score 2):

Definitely check out Chuck's library when it is released. But I would also urge you to record as much as you can yourself. With rocks, you're dealing with something that you can do indoors on a foley stage by yourself, so it's not too labor intensive or expensive. Or go out and find a remote area where you can push a bunch of rocks around or over cliffs, etc. (without hurting anyone or yourself!). If you record at 192k with a couple of decent mics you'll get some great material and build your library at the same time. Nothing beats a kit of custom recorded sounds.

Also remember that the biggest rocks will not always make the biggest sounds. I've learned this through experience - sometimes it's the small stuff, recorded at high resolutions and then pitched down, that will yield the monster sound you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To echo what the other guys said. I'm putting the finishing touches on my rock library now for release next week. If you sign up for my mailing list, you'll get an email as soon as it is ready: chuckrussomfx.com/mail.php I went out to the desert on 2 occasions, recorded at 192K, and tried to get as much rock action as I could, so there should be at lease a few hundred rock sounds in the finished library.  It was very tiring!

Comment: Downloaded it today. Have to say it rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Chuck Russom (http://www.chuckrussomfx.com/ is releasing one next week in the "Boutique" library format.  Small, specialized, and affordable.  He just posted a few behind the scenes videos here:  http://www.vimeo.com/crussom

Answer (score 0):

Genius! Perfect timing. Will tell my boss that we should buy it. Already subscribed to your list after you posted your metal library.

I have to say I'm am loving this idea of mini-libraries. If you need a specific thing it's perfect as you don't need to spend hundreds on a large all encompassing library when you're only after a few. Especially true if you've already got some of those large libraries.

Cheers guys!

Ian